# Background-image of body does not repeat to viewport

Tags: html, css

My website has a background that is composed of two images.

```
html{
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-image:url('../images/backgroundbottom.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:bottom;
}
body{
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: "arial", "times", "courier";
font-size: 10pt;
color:white;
background-image:url('../images/backgroundtop.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

The body background does not adapt to the dynamic environment of my website like the html does. The body background stops repeating at the right side, but the html extends to the entire viewpoint. I have tested this in Chrome, FireFox, Android and Safari.

The html and body elements do not fill the viewport. This issue is most likely being caused by a `div` that is pushing to the right side with a `position:absolute`.

How do I work around this issue?

Comment: Could you possibly give us more of the HTML code - or perhaps a link to the page, demonstrating the problem more clearly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is your friend in these situations... it will allow you to replicate your issue, and then we can see exactly what you mean (and possible fix it there for you)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding background-attachment:fixed;

```
background-repeat:x;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:bottom;
```